# Onclientclick is not working for in asp button

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Onclientclick is not working for me in asp button. The button is present inside update panel

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpLoad" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
     <asp:Button ID="btnProcess" runat="server" Text="Process" OnClientClick="alert('hi');" onClick="btnProcessing_Click" />
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnProcess" />
</Triggers>
```

Can someone help me where am i going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieved this with the help of jquery.

```
 $('#<%=btnProcess.ClientID%>').click(function () {
        alert('hi');
    });
```

It worked. Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 0):

```js
  function validate() {
            //if validation sucess return true otherwise return false.
            if (document.getElementById("txtSample").value != "") {
                return true;
            }
            alert('Enter a value');
            return false;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        Enter a value:<asp:TextBox ID="txtSample" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Click Me" OnClientClick="javascript:return validate();"
            OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


In aspx page::
=============

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Response.Write("The textbox value is " + txtSample.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PostBackTrigger` inside `UpdatePanel` to trigger both `OnClick` and `OnClientClick` events. Here's how:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnProcess" runat="server" Text="Process" OnClientClick="javascript:alert('hi');" onClick="btnProcess_Click" />
    </ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
   <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnProcess" />
</Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Bikee, I already have postbacktrigger in my updatepanel. Pls have a look. Onclick is working fine but onclientclick is not working.

Comment: @SurendraMourya, do you see any errors? Or have any additional code to show? The code works well in my VS locally.

Comment: this was the only part of code where i am facing issue. Also i am not getting any error neither in browser nor in code. It is not hitting onclientclick i think. i dont know why